# questions about PCA

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, pca, mathematica

If I have five variables, each with four sub-questions, In each sub-question, I have:
1 = I usually don't  do this at all
2 = I usually do this a little bit
3 = I usually do this a medium amount
4 = I usually do this a lot

If the values ​​of my five variables are the sum of their sub-questions' scores, do I need to standardize them if I want to use PCA? Do you recommend using correlation or covariance matrix to construct PCs?